# Why do people use setTimeout("func()", ... ) instead of setTimeout(func, ... )

Tags: javascript

I see this used a lot and I was told putting the function reference between quotes was bad because `setTimeout`/`setInterval` `evals` the reference. What is the actual difference between these two such that one is used over the other and why do I see this used so frequently even though it should be common knowledge that this one way is bad?

Comment: Because people are dumb. More politically correctly, because prevalence of use does not ever imply best practice... Use a piece of code based on its individual, intrinsic merits, not because it's the "common" or "cool" thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. People may not realize they can use the unquoted form.
2. The name referenced in the string may not yet be defined.
3. The quoted form gives you delayed execution:

   ```
   setTimeout("myFunction(1, 'hello')", 100)
   ```

   is easier to understand than:

   ```
   setTimeout(function () { myFunction(1, 'hello') }, 100)
   ```

   and this doesn't do what the author wants:

   ```
   setTimeout(myFunction(1, 'hello'), 100)
   ```

Comment: The last one *does work*. It just doesn't do what some people might expect.

Comment: You mean it doesn't raise an error.  It doesn't do what the author intended. Clarified above.

Comment: Given that you're the author in this case I can't argue with that. My point was more that you might have `myFunction` return a function or an eval-able string.

Comment: I think #2 would be better stated as "the expression is evaluated each time in the global context" since it may not contain a name or identifier but an expression that resolves to something callable. For #3, the quoted expression doesn't give "delayed execution" but re-evaluation of the expression (in the global context) each time.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main differences between these two forms:

```
setTimeout("myFunc()", 100);
```

and

```
setTimeout(myFunc, 100);
```

The first is less efficient and it evaluates the function in the global scope so you can't pass it a local function or any function that isn't global.

In a look at the efficiency argument, if you wanted to call a function you had in your code would you write:

```
x = myFunc();
```

or would you write:

```
x = eval("myFunc()");
```

Of course, you'd write the first one because:

1. That's how you normally write javascript
2. The function reference can be resolved once in the first pass of the interpreter rather than each time it executes
3. Minifiers/optimizers can rename your symbol with the first, but not the second.
4. You can call local functions with the first one, but the second requires a global function
5. `eval()` is a fairly heavyweight thing that should be used only when there is no other better way to do it.

FYI, [this jsPerf comparison](http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-direct-reference) indicates that the `eval()` version is 96% slower.  The performance might not matter in some circumstances, but you can get the idea how much less efficient it is.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it also prevents memory leaks.

Doesn't leak X:

```
var x = $("loading");
setTimeout("createTree(1);", 0);
```

Leak's X:

```
var x = $("loading");
setTimeout(function(){createTree(1);}, 0);
```

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Dennis—unlikely, but possible. @Kernel James—can you explain how the memory leak occurs? Or post an example of it in action? Or why jQuery is involved?

Comment: This makes no sense.  The `setTimeout()` should have no effect on what happens to `x`.

Comment: I was deducing it from the behavior of setTimeout. E.g., `function runme(){var x=1; setTimeout("alert(x);",1000)} function runme2(){var x=1; setTimeout(function(){alert(x);},1000)}` Calling `runme()` will throw an error because x is out of scope, eligible for GC. Calling `runme2()` will alert x, because it is in scope and not eligible for GC until after 1 second has passed.